# Android convert physical screen measurements to density one (not runtime!)

Tags: android, dpi

So, as far as I know, we can use next formula:
`density = SQRT(width*width+height*height)/screen_size`.
For example, Nexus 6 (6.0", 1_440*2_560) should give **490 dpi** (approx.), but Android Studio Preview screen shows this device with **560 dpi**.
What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28477572/794088 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041594/how-does-quantized-density-affect-image-resource-selection-and-scaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the Nexus 6, the manufacturer density is 560 but the physical density is about 493. Always think about the manufacturer density before think scale factor.

Answer (score 3):

Although each device has its own screen density, Android includes the device into the nearest density "bucket":

- 420 dpi
- 560 dpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi

As seen in Android Studio:

[image]

Although the Nexus 6 and 6P have different physical screen densities, the same drawable resource will be used for both devices.